# What about an opinion.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Often i want to ask for opinions and use polls for some questions?

They are closed each time because they are subjective and argumentative - which is the whole idea i ask them.

So can we add another stackoverflow for a more relaxed way to handle subjective questions. Even flame wars might be worth reading from time to time.

Comment: http://www.surveymonkey.com/

Comment: -1 to flame wars being worth reading. (And yes, flame on)

Comment: Shut up, Jon B - you fun-hating authoritarian. It's vitally important that we can express to one another our preferences, as programmers, for buttering toast.

Comment: Stuff it, Shog9, you waffle-hating toast-eating SOB.

Comment: Pancakes are king, you Skeet-damned idiots!

Comment: Waffle-hating? Why, you insolent Java-monkey!

Comment: My eyes are bleeding maple syrup tears

Answer (score 6):

Maybe SO should just host a regular poll, Slashdot-style. Let folks submit their ideas here on Meta, and pick them off in order of popularity... The question could be owned by the Community user (so no badges or rep for whoever suggested it), and the rate at which new polls are posted would be [controlled by the system](http://codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001228.html).

Yeah, there'd still be a regular stream of worthless questions. But it'd provide a controlled means for users to [have their fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/), and, hopefully **get it out of their systems**.

Comment: I like the idea of the occasional sidebar poll.  Those of us who hate them can block them via preferences, while everyone else has a harmless way to let off some steam.

Comment: they would _never_ get it out of their systems! Send these people away from SO!

Answer (score 3):

You sure can. Head over to http://www.stackexchange.com and create one.

<strike>Of course, you'll have to pay for that privilege.</strike> Not anymore. Now you just need to get a community critical mass to agree with you and StackExchange will run it.